# How to detect if control is button or not in C#

Tags: c#

I wanna change all buttons's cursor type to "Hand" in my form. But the code is not working. Can anyone help pls? )
This is code:

```
 foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
 {
      if (control is Button)
      {
           control.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
      }
  }
```

Comment: Is this ASP.NET? Winform? Xamarin? What are the types of `Control` and `Button`?

Answer (score 1):

You are correctly checking if the control is of type Button.  But you need to cast it to become a Button control (not a generic control) before changing the Cursor.

```
if (control is Button)
{
    (control as Button).Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pattern-matching grammar. Try this:

```cs
 foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
 {
      if (control is Button b)
      {
           b.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
      }
  }
```